# Pandas groupby: storing only indexes

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, dataframe

I have a large Pandas dataframe (200,000 entries and 16 columns). I want to group all indexes by `colour` and `code`. Importantly, I want to

1) minimise the computational effort by excluding all irrelevant columns during `groupby()` and

2) minimise the memory required by only storing the indexes per `colour` - `code` pair.

An example dataframe is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                   'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                             'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                   'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                           'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                   'irrelevant1': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo','bar','bar',
                                     'foo','bar','bar'],
                   'irrelevant2': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo','bar','bar',
                                     'foo','bar','bar'],
                   'irrelevant3': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo','bar','bar',
                                     'foo','bar','bar'],
                   'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'irrelevant1', 'irrelevant2', 'irrelevant3', 'amount'])
```

My attempt:

```
df_reduced = df[['code','colour']] # I am manually removing the irrelevant columns before performing groupby()
gb = df_reduced.groupby(['code','colour'])
gb_dict = dict(list(gb))
gb_dict['one','white']
  code colour
1  one  white
6  one  white
```

However, I do not want to store the `code` or `colour` columns at all. In other words, I want `gb_dict['one','white']` to return `[1,6]` alone. How can I achieve this?

Also, I feel like manually defining `df_reduced` is unnecessary, surely I should be able to limit the columns that I want to include in `groupby()` more elegantly?  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want groups dict?

```
>>> groups = df.groupby(['code','colour']).groups
>>> groups['one','white']
[1L, 6L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems right. Is the performance of this affected by the number of columns in the df? i.e. would it be better to first do `df_reduced = df[['code','colour']]` and then run this on `df_reduced`? I don't want to unnecessarily group all the irrelevant columns.

Comment: @Zhubarb as `df[['code','colour']]` builds a bunch of new objects (a new dataframe included), this alone can lead to more performance loss than possible  groupby performance gain from smaller dataframe (not sure if any exists, as all computations on additional columns is done after grouping in transform or aggregate phase)